# Using rethink to watch geographic point changes

Tags: rethinkdb

Just started using Rethink and loving it so far. I'm wondering how I can watch changes to a table based on geographic points. Let's say I have a "units" table with a "geography" index as "geo".

I want to run a query that listens in to determine if any new points are added or removed from a radius. I'm having trouble figuring this out and there isn't much content available out there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This currently isn't possible with RethinkDB.  A version of this using an unindexed `filter` is currently scheduled for 2.2: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4063